# Security risk with Garmin GPS device

Tags: gps

The IT dept at work refuses to install Garmin software on our PCs because they say that connect a Garmin GPS device to a machine is a security risk.
What is the risk?

Comment: Ask them. Not us.

Comment: If by "them" you mean the IT dept, they will not engage in discussion about it.

Comment: Ok. We can speculate, but not know. It can be a multitude of reasons, more or less specific to that piece of software. Bear in mind that *all* software is a security risk, but some software is also useful to your employer. Limiting it to software that is useful (to them) reduces security risks.

Comment: The relevant question is: what is the ***impact*** to your company if something undesired happened? We can't tell you what type of risk assessment they have performed. It could be any 3rd party software, it could be GPS coordinates being leaked to Garmin, it could be the GPS device that's seen as a threat. You really need to ask them.

Comment: They likely haven't performed any risk assessment. They see that you have to plug the device into the computer and automatically say no. So I am seeking information about the risks.